# Negative-margin control get clipped when resizing the window in WPF

Tags: wpf, resize, margin, negative-number, clipped

I try to understand why a border element get clipped when reducing the width of the main window.
Please take a look the code block below.

```
    <Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="500" Name="MainWin">
    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <Border Background="Blue" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Black" Width="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=Width}" />
        <Grid Grid.Row="1" Margin="0">
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="Black">
                <Border Background="White" Width="150" Height="150" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"
                        Margin="0,-100,0,0">

                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=Width}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"
                               HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" />

                </Border>
            </StackPanel>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Background="Red" />
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Background="Yellow" />
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Here is what the border appears in the original window width:

Non-resized window

[image]

As you can see that the border is displayed outside its container because of the negative top margin, -100 in this case. This is what I expect to have for the border. But when I reduce the main window width to reach the right edge of the red rectangle the outside part of the border get clipped.

Resized window

[image]

I have tried to place this border element inside a custom StackPanel which overrides ArrangeOverride, MeasureOverride and GetLayoutClip method but unfortunately these methods are not invoked when the main window is being resized.

I appreciate if somebody can explain me what the reason is and how to work around with this issue.
Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the explanation of @Marks, here is my solution

1. Create a custom grid and overrides MeasureOverride method
2. Replace the inner grid by this custom grid

CustomGrid class

```
public class CustomGrid : Grid
{
    private double _originalHeight = 0;

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size constraint)
    {
        Size? size = null;
        if (constraint.Width <= 300)
        {
            size = new Size(constraint.Width, _originalHeight);
        }
        else
        {
            size = base.MeasureOverride(constraint);
            _originalHeight = constraint.Height;

        }
        return size.Value;
    }

}
```

XAML code

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:wpfApplication1="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="300" Width="500" Name="MainWin">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Border Background="Blue" Grid.Row="0" BorderBrush="Black" Width="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=Width}" />
    <wpfApplication1:CustomGrid Grid.Row="1">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Background="Black">
            <Border Background="White" Width="150" Height="150" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"
                    Margin="0,-100,0,0">

                <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=Width}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Bottom" />

            </Border>
        </StackPanel>
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Background="Red" />
        <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Background="Yellow" />
    </wpfApplication1:CustomGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You're binding the blue border's `Width` to the MainWindow's `Width`.
   For the future: if you want to bind to the width of any `FrameworkElement` bind to its `ActualWidth` property.
2. The order in which WPF draws its stuff is quite dependent on the containing control. I'd say in your case the outer `Grid` draws its children *that need updating* in the order they are defined. So you're good to go as long as the inner grid changes along with the border. This is the case as long as the `Width` of the third column changes. Once it's at 0 there's no more change so it doesn't get updated.
3. (2) is speculation =)
4. don't do (1), there's no need for it
5. Use one Grid

Some XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>        
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="150" />
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Border Background="Blue" BorderBrush="Black" Grid.ColumnSpan="3"/>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Grid.Row="1" Background="Black" >
      <Border Background="White" Width="150" Height="150" BorderBrush="Black" BorderThickness="2"  Margin="0,-100,0,0">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=MainWin, Path=ActualWidth}" FontSize="14" FontWeight="Bold"
                           HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                           VerticalAlignment="Center" />
      </Border>
    </StackPanel>
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Background="Red" />
    <StackPanel Grid.Column="2" Grid.Row="1" Background="Yellow" />          
</Grid>
```

Comment: Thank you for the explanation Markus.
1. This is just my example. I just wanted the border has the main window's width
2. Yes. I can see the point. I have tried to create a custom grid which overrides 3 methods mentioned above and they are invoked when the window is resized.
3. :)
4. Thanks for the advice
5. My actual application issue is in the case of my example. We need to have 2 grids. When I mean is the inner grid is the container of a user control
I will find a work around based on your explanation at point 2.